# Python 3 IDLE won't run

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle, python-3.8

When I double-click on the IDLE to run it, nothing appears on my screen. I have tried reinstalling Python multiple times with multiple different versions. It works on different accounts on the same computer, but for some reason refuses to open. If anyone could give a solution I would be most grateful.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: I am on Windows 10 Pro Version 1909

Answer (score 0):

Please consider adding python to your path.